# What to use Multiprocessing or multi-threading in Python?

Tags: python

I am involved in a project recently which has been written in python. All files are getting analyzed serially one after other, so taking approx 1 hour in completion. My task is to reduce this time.

I am not sure what should I use in python : Multi-thread or multi-process to run file analysis in parallel.

Please suggest.

Thank you.

Comment: What type of analysis is being performed? Also, are you looking to process multiple files in parallel or multiple parts of each file in parallel.

Comment: I am trying to run multiple files parallel so that I can reduce completion time, after some research on Google I get to know that I should use "popen" in python to do so. I am trying to get grip in this area by running some examples. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe this is what you're looking for.
https://nathangrigg.com/2015/04/python-threading-vs-processes

[possible answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19326582/multiprocess-vs-multithread-python-time-taken)

Do you also need a brief description of these two & differences?

To be short, if one of your sub-problems has to wait another finishes, Multi Thread is good (for example, I/O heavy operations); by contrast, if your sub-problems could really happen at the same time, Multi Processing is suggested. However, you won't create more processes than your number of cores.
[maybe this will explain you better](https://www.quantstart.com/articles/Parallelising-Python-with-Threading-and-Multiprocessing)

Comment: Thank you for the link, it is good.

Answer (score 2):

It heavily depends on the type of analysis. Here is a  simple rule of thumb to give hints:

- if the process is memory bound, keep it serial
- if it is io bound, use multithreading - optimal number of threads depends on the percentage of time spent in io waiting
- if it is cpu-bound, use muti-processing with a number or process equal to the number of available cores

If you cannot be sure a priori, just experiment... But never forget that no method is absolutely better that the others in all possible use cases